# Encyclopedia of aliens

Tags: story-identification, books, aliens

As a kid I had a book about aliens. It was a pseudo-encyclopedia of sorts with different kinds of articles and chapters about extraterrestrials. I was so young at the time, I don't remember a great deal about the text, but many of the pictures were quite striking. My dad got it for me and we loved it, though my mother was not so keen on some of the gore. As I remember, there was a disembodied eye on the cover and one image inside the book was of a hand holding several eyeballs.

Comment: Did the bookcover show a steel door with a hole being melted in the center, with a tentacle coming through the hole and a single eye peering through?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Alien World: The Complete Illustrated Guide](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1769794) by Steven Eisler

This was an art book of sci-fi aliens illustrated by various authors, with lurid descriptions invented by Mr. Eisler.

Disembodied eye on the cover:

[image]

Hand holding several eyeballs:

[image]

Comment: How about this: http://www.terrantradeauthority.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/AlienWorld004.jpg?w=863  (Found here: http://www.terrantradeauthority.com/other-books/alien-world-the-complete-illustrated-guide/)

Comment: Confirmed, that's the handful of eyeballs I remember. Nice catch!

Comment: Nice find! Gotta be it.

Comment: THAT'S THE ONE!!! Wow, for some twenty years my Google Fu has failed me! But, I figured if just one person could remember some of those images . . .  Thanks so much. I'll have to see if I can find this somewhere, now that I have the title. : ))

Comment: I bow to your, well, something or other.  Good find.

Answer (score 7):

The likeliest answer is "Barlowe's Guide to Extraterrestrials".

I can't vouch for the hand holding the eyeballs but maybe that was a different cover.

[https://www.amazon.com/Barlowes-Guide-Extraterrestrials-Science-Literature/dp/0894803247](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0894803247)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answer, but this isn't it. : (